# Vertical Align Header with Alert and Button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I'm trying to vertically align a title header, an alert and two buttons.
My goal is to make the width of the alert bigger even if its content is short. My problem is that since I uses `span` for the alert, I need to put `display: inline-block` in its style but by doing that, the alignment with the header gets misaligned. BTW, I'm using Bootstrap.

Here's the image of what I want to happen:

[image: Example of what I want to happen]

Here's my HTML:

```
<h1>
    <span>This will be a very long title</span>
    <span class="alert custom">
        This is notification!
    </span>
    <span class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn button-round">O</button>
        <button class="btn button-round">X</button>
    </span>
</h1>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.button-round {
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  background: green;
}

.custom{
  font-size: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle of my current code:
[JSFiddle of my current code](https://jsfiddle.net/fczbe58L/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this easy, you should use flex :

```css
.button-round {
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  background: green;
  margin: auto
}

.custom {
  font-size: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  /* added */
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
}


/* end added */
```

```html
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
<h1>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <span>This will be a very long title</span>
  <span class="alert custom">
  This is notification!
</span>
  <span class="pull-right">
  <button class="btn button-round">O</button>
  <button class="btn button-round">X</button>
</span>
</h1>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fczbe58L/1/